# I think i have done some mistake in allocating segmentcontrol..i am getting an error [unrecognized selector sent to instance]

Tags: ios

```
    Segcontrol = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mind", @"Munches", nil]];
    Segcontrol.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)/4.5, self.view.frame.size.height/4, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)/1.8, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)/12);
    [Segcontrol addTarget:Segcontrol action:@selector(segtap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [Segcontrol setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    [Segcontrol setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    Segcontrol.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    [self.view addSubview:Segcontrol];


-(void)segtap:(id)sender{
    if (Segcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {

        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];


    }else if (Segcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex==1){

        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];


    }

}
```

Comment: show your **segtap :** method

Comment: i think these line of code is crashing your app
[Segcontrol addTarget:Segcontrol action:@selector(segtap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
Maybe you forgot to implement these method.

Comment: No actually i implemented that method also

Comment: Show us the full error of the unrecognized selector. Which selector and which instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the `SegmentControl` object *`Segcontrol`* as target to the segment action. Rather than this the object `self` should be added as target. Change the code like below and you are good to go.

```
[Segcontrol addTarget:self action:@selector(segtap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement segtap method like this.

```
 -(void)segtap:(id)sender
 {
     switch (Segcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex)
     {
     case 0:
         NSLog(@"Index 0 selected");
         break;
     case 1:
        NSLog(@"Index 1 selected");
        break;
     }
 }
```

I think you might be forgotten to pass argument to the method.

Comment: Nope still its getting crash